# Converting Program With Only A Constructor To One With A Main Method Instead

Tags: java, constructor

My instructor is having trouble grading my assignment. I created the following program in BlueJ, and he most likely uses Eclipse. The problem is that I couldn't get BlueJ to fire up any piece of code with the main method, so I just opted to use a constructor instead. A copy/paste of my BlueJ code into Eclipse shows it to be problematic the way it is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Misspelled
```

How would I convert my constructor-only program below into a program with a working main method? I don't need the constructor any more.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RandomGame
{
int usersScore = 0;

public RandomGame()
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] wrongWords = {"mispelled","kobra", "wishfull", "adress", "changable","independant", "emberrass", "cieling", "humerous", "wierd"} ;
    String[] rightWords = {"arctic", "miscellaneous", "piece", "prejudice", "grateful","ecstasy", "fascinate", "definite", "changeable", "conscious"};
    double randomNumber;
    int randomNumberInt;
    String wordToCheck;



            //Display Rules
    System.out.printf("Enter Either 'y' or 'n'");

            //Keep Looping Game
    while(usersScore < 5)
    {
            //Generate A Random Number
    randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();     //Math.round(10 * Math.random());
    randomNumberInt = ((int)(randomNumber));


            //Display User's Score
    System.out.printf("\n\nCurrent Score: %d\n", usersScore);

            //Check Place Value Of Random Number In Array
    if(randomNumber %2 == 0)
    {
        wordToCheck = rightWords[randomNumberInt];

        System.out.printf("Correct?: %s\n", wordToCheck);
        rightCheck(userInput.next());
    }
    else
    {
        wordToCheck = wrongWords[randomNumberInt];

        System.out.printf("Correct?: %s\n", wordToCheck);
        wrongCheck(userInput.next());
    }

   }
    //System.out.printf(wordToCheck);



}

public double generateRandomNumber()
{
    double randNum;

    randNum = Math.round(10 * Math.random());

    return(randNum);
}

public boolean rightCheck(String usersAnswer)
{
    if(usersAnswer.equals("y"))
    {
        System.out.printf("Correct! from rightCheck");
        usersScore++;

        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.printf("Incorrect from rightCheck");
        usersScore--;

        return(false);
    }
}

public boolean wrongCheck(String usersAnswer)
{
    if(usersAnswer.equals("n"))
    {
        System.out.printf("Correct! from wrongCheck");
        usersScore++;

        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.printf("Incorrect from wrongCheck");
        usersScore--;

        return(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The constructor is not for this. It is to initialize the state of the object, not to do any kind of processing. - I'm sure the IDE you're using can handle a main method, as it is a MUST for all java programs. (May be you created the wrong kind of project you should choose something like "Java Application").

Answer (score 1):

one way is to create another class to hold your main method

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        RandomGame rGame = new RandomGame();
    }
}
```

(Note: the name of the .java file must be Main.java in the above case)

otherwise you can just add the main() to your RandomGame class in the following way

```
public static void main (String args[])
    {
        RandomGame rGame = new RandomGame();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following steps :

1. Change the constructor to main method `public static void main(String[] args)`
2. Change all the private/public methods used in the constructor as `static` methods
3. Either change the member variable `usersScore` as static or create instance of RandomGame instead main to track the value of `usersScore`

> *Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime*

Answer (score 0):

Write `public static void main(String args[])`

Inside the main, make an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

The code below has made the following changes:

- Added constructor logic to a main method
- Made methods static
- Made field static

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class RandomGame {
      static int usersScore = 0;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

          String[] wrongWords = { "mispelled", "kobra", "wishfull", "adress",
                  "changable", "independant", "emberrass", "cieling", "humerous",
                  "wierd" };
          String[] rightWords = { "arctic", "miscellaneous", "piece",
                  "prejudice", "grateful", "ecstasy", "fascinate", "definite",
                  "changeable", "conscious" };
          double randomNumber;
          int randomNumberInt;
          String wordToCheck;

          // Display Rules
          System.out.printf("Enter Either 'y' or 'n'");

          // Keep Looping Game
          while (usersScore < 5) {
              // Generate A Random Number
              randomNumber = generateRandomNumber(); // Math.round(10 *
                                                      // Math.random());
              randomNumberInt = ((int) (randomNumber));

              // Display User's Score
              System.out.printf("\n\nCurrent Score: %d\n", usersScore);

              // Check Place Value Of Random Number In Array
              if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
                  wordToCheck = rightWords[randomNumberInt];

                  System.out.printf("Correct?: %s\n", wordToCheck);
                  rightCheck(userInput.next());
              } else {
                  wordToCheck = wrongWords[randomNumberInt];

                  System.out.printf("Correct?: %s\n", wordToCheck);
                  wrongCheck(userInput.next());
              }

          }
          // System.out.printf(wordToCheck);

      }

      public static double generateRandomNumber() {
          double randNum;

          randNum = Math.round(10 * Math.random());

          return (randNum);
      }

      public static boolean rightCheck(String usersAnswer) {
          if (usersAnswer.equals("y")) {
              System.out.printf("Correct! from rightCheck");
              usersScore++;

              return (true);
          } else {
              System.out.printf("Incorrect from rightCheck");
              usersScore--;

              return (false);
          }
      }

      public static boolean wrongCheck(String usersAnswer) {
          if (usersAnswer.equals("n")) {
              System.out.printf("Correct! from wrongCheck");
              usersScore++;

              return (true);
          } else {
              System.out.printf("Incorrect from wrongCheck");
              usersScore--;

              return (false);
          }
      }
  }
  ```